# What are some practices of space exploration that are no longer acceptable?

Tags: design, failure, procedure

I'm sure that for every good idea that made it into a spaceship design, there had to be plenty of bad ideas. There's most likely a bunch of old designs (or practices) that passed previously, but would be scoffed at today by our new standards. I'm mostly interested in the older designs that were used in space exploration that ***would be immediately declined today*** due to any number of reasons. Anything that was implemented/used in previous space exploration that would be absolutely banned by standards today would be a fit for an answer to this question.

---

*For instance, lets assume we were in the 1980's attempting a new chemical composition of solid rocket fuel that ended up releasing 2-3 times the amount of acoustic vibrations than was expected.*

**Answering the following:** "Why would we never have let this happen today, and why did we let this happen then?" **Would be a great answer.** I would like explanation of the incident to be in detail explaining:

**Why it failed. What new regulations were put in place because of it. How we would do it now.**

Comment: Generally, we only allow these types of list questions if there is a reasonable limit to the number of examples people might provide. I'm not so sure there is a good limit here.

Comment: If you restricted it to a particular era, it *might* be ok.

Comment: A bit open-ended but I love the question.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be a good candidate for a Community Wiki, since it essentially solicits a list of answers instead of a canonical one.

Comment: @paul Community wiki? Also this is old, I can close it if not objective.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn What's wrong with making it Community wiki?

Comment: @AlexHajnal Nothing, I was asking what that was. I genuinely don't know.

Comment: [This page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) has a pretty good overview.  In essence (nearly) everyone can edit a community answer and noöne gains/loses reputation on it.  IOW, the answer has been given to the entire community to improve or expand upon.  I'm unclear as to whether/how this applies at the question level though.

Comment: Oh, neat, I have no idea how to migrate this though.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I flagged this question asking a moderator to provide more info about community wiki status.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Community wiki questions should no longer be used for open-ended lists. If such questions are allowed, they can still use community wiki answers.

Comment: @called2voyage Hate to say it but the question side of things WRT community wikis is still clear as mud to me (and likely others).  Are there detailed docs/guidelines/usage notes/etc. on this (especially from the question side of things)?  I have searched, haven't found anything concrete, it's all been fairly vague.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Unfortunately, no. SE has all but stopped supporting it.

Comment: I kinda got the feeling...

Comment: Ah... makes me feel less dumb for being unaware of it now. I mean ive heard of putting community lists in meta too. But usually its a list of questions in answer form.

Answer (score 17):

One prominent example are the original Apollo hatches which opened towards the inside of the capsule and took a minimum of five minutes to open. During a ground training mission, a fire broke out inside the capsule.  The pressure increased and the astronauts inside couldn't open the hatches to escape. Had the hatches opened towards the outside and had a quick-release been provided<sup>1</sup>, the astronauts might have survived.

The result was three dead astronauts and a redesign of the capsule leading to outwards-opening, quick-to-open hatches.

<sup>1</sup> Ironically, the difficult-to-open Apollo 1 hatch design was a well-intentioned but poorly thought-out safety feature instituted in the wake of the [Mercury-Redstone 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Redstone_4) hatch incident.

Answer (score 11):

Not wearing pressure suits during critical phases of flight (eg. ascent or reentry) would not be accepted today (as a lesson learned from [Soyuz 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_11)).

Comment: A lesson learned, but [not quickly enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Challenger_disaster#Cause_and_time_of_death) [by everyone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Columbia_disaster#Crew_survivability_aspects) (granted, it wouldn't have made a significant difference in either case, _but still_).

Comment: Wait, so the crew cabin in the challenger disaster survived breakup and the crew were apparently alive until they hit the surface?

Comment: @saolof the results are inconclusive. But there is evidence, that at least some of the crew of challenger was able to act and were alive until impact.

Answer (score 11):

The first liquid fueled rocket was constructed by Robert Goddard in 1926.  Its design placed the engine at the top and the fuel at the bottom.  He thought that this would provide natural stability but in fact [it had no effect on stability whatsoever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_rocket_fallacy) and only served to complicate the design.  The engine-at-top layout was quickly discarded and is seldom revisited except in niche applications (launch escape systems come to mind).

[image: Robert Goddard stands by the world's first liquid-fueled rocket]

<sup>Esther C. Goddard via NASA and Wikipedia, Public domain</sup>

A replica of this rocket is currently [on view](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/model-rocket-liquid-fuel-16-march-1926-goddard) at the Smithsonian's Udvar-Hazy Center in Chantilly, Virginia.  An original rocket, likely containing parts of the one used for the first liquid-fueled flight, [can be seen](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/rocket-liquid-fuel-4-may-1926-goddard) at the National Air and Space Museum in Washington DC.

This rocket and its design has been asked about of few times before (the first two are the most apropos in this context):

- [Why are satellites and other payloads always placed at the top of rockets?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/why-are-satellites-and-other-payloads-always-placed-at-the-top-of-rockets)
- [Why are Rocket engines at the base of the rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9682/why-are-rocket-engines-at-the-base-of-the-rocket)
- [Which part(s) of the Goddard Rocket is(are) the rocket, and why (actually) no fins?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17939/which-parts-of-the-goddard-rocket-isare-the-rocket-and-why-actually-no-fi)
- [How did Goddard's rocket reach 41 feet altitude in under 2.5 seconds?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/how-did-goddards-rocket-reach-41-feet-altitude-in-under-2-5-seconds)

Comment: This would also be a great fit for the question "Why don't we put engines at the top of the rocket?" I don't think this man was mentioned, and I cant seem to find that question. Nobody mentioned that someone had actually done it, only that it should not be done.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn [This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9682/why-are-rocket-engines-at-the-base-of-the-rocket) is probably the one you're thinking of.  [This one](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/why-are-satellites-and-other-payloads-always-placed-at-the-top-of-rockets) and [this one](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3385/why-was-the-shuttles-lox-tank-on-top-of-the-lh2-tank-since-that-makes-it-more) also touch on the topic.

Answer (score 6):

Approval of a manned system that does not offer a launch abort options through out launch profile. The space shuttle combination of widely spaced solid rockets and a side ways stacked design made for a large number of failure modes that were not survivable, increasing both engineering cost and risk.

Though having said this, launch abort for BFR may be a complex process and inherently risky process given need to have almost but not quite empty tanks for touch down, and that touch down needing to be at some form of prepared pad.

Launching satellites with live nuclear reactors also comes to mind, though would guess that pretty much any sensible manned mission will probably need one or more.

Improvements to reactor design and robotics would make it more possible to launch fuel elements separately in capsules designed for maximum safety (including only flying sub critical amounts) and only combine as a critical mass inside a reactor once in orbit.

Comment: WRT your first paragraph I counter you the Ares-I.  [See the second paragraph here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares_I#Analysis_and_testing) - and that's just for starters.

Answer (score 3):

[image: ESA description of a booster exploding]
<sup>Source: ESA; Image: [Explosions of satellites & rocket bodies](http://www.esa.int/spaceinimages/Images/2008/03/Explosions_of_satellites_rocket_bodies), [ESA Standard License](http://www.esa.int/spaceinimages/ESA_Multimedia/Copyright_Notice_Images)</sup>

In the last 60 years, there have been over "4800 launches [that] have placed some 6000 satellites into orbit. Today, less than a thousand of them are still operational."

<sup>Source: [Space Debris Mitigation](http://www.spacesafetymagazine.com/space-debris/mitigation/), *Space Safety Magazine*</sup>

One aspect that has changed has been Space Debris Mitigation.

> In 1995, NASA issued a comprehensive set of orbital debris mitigation guidelines.
>   ...
>   The space debris mitigation guidelines provide a framework for what needs to be done [to declutter Low Earth Orbit to hopefully lessen collisions and other problems such as exploding boosters which add to the space junk problem]. The international debris mitigation standards have been developed in the ISO-24113:2011 which defines the primary space debris mitigation requirements applicable to all elements of unmanned systems launched into, or passing through, near-Earth space, including launch vehicle orbital stages, operating spacecraft and any objects released as part of normal operations or disposal actions.

<sup>Source: [Space Debris Mitigation](http://www.spacesafetymagazine.com/space-debris/mitigation/), *Space Safety Magazine*</sup>

Comment: Can't put my finger on it but this answer seems a bit awkward to me.  Maybe you could add a specific example?  e.g. "In the past A was done not realizing that it would cause B.  This led to C being done instead leaving A unthinkable today."  The design of [Soviet orbital nuclear reactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US-A#Other_concerns) and how they were decommissioned comes to mind but there may well be better examples.

Comment: Always attribute quotes. Not doing so is plagiarism, and can lead to the post being downvoted or deleted.

Comment: Same for images.  WRT the quote I hadn't realized that most of the answer was copied and pasted from elsewhere (I thought you'd written it - maybe that's why it sounded awkward to me?).  @NathanTuggy Man I wish I could upvote your comment more than once.